# The Agora Unity plugin fails to stream video to other users. In the log, I have a "Failed to initialize encoder" error

Tags: agora.io

On one windows 10 machine, Agora for Unity fails to encode video.  On another, it works just fine.  I can't figure out what the difference is though... maybe a missing h264 codec?  Any feedback appreciated.

```
INFO    10:59:13:124  23428; Thread with name:VideoEncodeThread started 
ERROR   10:59:13:124  32176; Failed to initialize encoder
INFO    10:59:13:124  11948; Thread with name:VideoProcessThread started 
INFO    10:59:13:124  32176; agora::media::VideoEngine::setCodec: index=1 width=640 height=360 framerate=15
INFO    10:59:13:124  32176; agora::media::VideoEngine::setCodec: Intra Request = 0
INFO    10:59:13:124  23428; Thread with name:VideoEncodeThread stopped
INFO    10:59:13:125  53128; Thread with name:VideoEncodeThread started 
ERROR   10:59:13:125  32176; Failed to initialize encoder
ERROR   10:59:13:125  32176; agora::media::VideoEngine::setCodec: VCM Could not register send codec 1, H264
INFO    10:59:13:125  32176; agora::media::VideoEngine::EnableLowBitRateStream: dual streams enabled 1 share 0 details 0
INFO    10:59:13:125  32176; agora::media::VideoEngine::h264WebInteropEnable: enable 0
INFO    10:59:13:125  32176; agora::media::VideoEngine::setCaptureDevice: index=0
```